# ngx-toastr not displaying until I refresh the page

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr

I am using ngx-toastr in my application and after each deployment, the toastr messages doesn't show until I refresh the page and try again. Only after I refresh it starts working normally without issues.

1. We are using Google Chrome
2. The Toastr container is being created, but the toast message itself is not being displayed
3. We are not using CDN.
4. No conflict with bootstrap css
5. CSS is added properly into style.css (@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';)

[image]